# Inform Angular frontend when state in Node backend (MongoDB) changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I want a real-time update on Angular frontend when state changes in MongoDB. What are my choices? Are there any other ways than, for ex. using socket.io?

Scenario - user creates a reminder, sets a date on which email will arrive in his mail box. Now for adding and removing reminders I can mimic real-time on front end side, because I know when user invokes some action that leads to a state change, but I also have a text next to every reminder - "Email was sent" or "Email not sent yet". Because I use cron jobs to send emails on my backend, front end cant know about it.

Its my first project where I code my backend, so I just wonder maybe there are some other ways than implementing lots of redundant stuff just to make one small feature to work?

NodeJs + Express + Angular6 + MongoDB

Comment: https://socket.io/ is really a consistent solution to send message from back to front. You should really consider it.

Comment: @jbrtmd, yes it is in my radar, but for now I have just one tiny feature to implement, so need to look for other ways, if there are any

Comment: You can also create an AJAX call every X seconds/minutes/hours to check the reminder state (according to your cron job). With this solution, you can get rid socket.io but it will not be realtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) the newest and coolest feature of MongoDB 3.6 for accessing real time changes from database.

**Sample Node.js Code**:

```
const collection = db.collection('example');
const changeStream = collection.watch();
const next = await changeStream.next();
```

Comment: Sounds like the best option here! I will just need to check can it be done through Mongoose. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't backend process only ? How do you notify your frontend ?

Comment: Use socket for that purpose.

Comment: Sir without this tech it's not possible to notify the frontend about db change detected on server.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a polling service using angular and rxjs. The service will check your database on a specific interval.

```
this.subscription = Observable.interval(1000).startWith(1)
.mergeMap(() => this.statusService.getStatus())
.subscribe((next) => {
 this.state = next;
 })
```

You can use [rxjs interval operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html) for polling

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that something like this is the only option. Ok, I will wait to see if someone propose something else