# Observable Angular don't work how I expect

Tags: angular, observable

My table don't update when a new product arrives I have to reload to see the results and that is not what I want. My expected result: when a new product is added from backend to frontend must be updated the table, this is my code:

**Product.service.ts**

```js
getProducts(): Observable<Products[]> {
  return this.http.get<Products[]>(this.BASE_URL);
}
```

**Admin-products.component.ts**

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((data) => {
    this.listOfData = data;
    console.log("data", data);
  });
}
```

***Admin-products.component.html***

```html
<nz-table
  #sortTable
  [nzData]="listOfData"
  nzTableLayout="fixed"
  nzShowPagination
  nzShowSizeChanger
>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let column of listOfColumn">{{ column.title }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of sortTable.data">
      <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.price }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.type }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.category }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.subCategory }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.amount }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

I don't know what I missing here, maybe the problem is my server in *nodejs with express* this is my server response:

***Nodejs Server***

```js
router.get("/products", (req, res) => {
  mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM products", (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.json(rows);
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

any idea?

Comment: So the available products are visible when you open the page and you want it to update immediatly when a new product is added?

Comment: When i get it right, you want update your frontend when there is a new entry in the backend?? At the moment your frontend cant know this. You call your backend only once onInit. You could make a button "refresh" that makes a call to the backend and update the data. Or something that make a polling to the backend. Or you search something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534330/inform-angular-frontend-when-state-in-node-backend-mongodb-changes/51535149

Comment: @xDrago yes that is exactly what i want.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 thanks I will check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missunderstand Obersvables. They work here as expected and will fire an event when the request completed, so the data gets displayed in your table. But you always have to make a request first. You have "to ask the server" for new data.

How should you obeservable know, that a new product was added? The server is not gonna tell your client "hey I have new items, ask me to send you some".

What you can do is:

1. Use a `setInterval` function to make a new request every X seconds to get new products aswell
2. Add a Refresh Button to ask for new data manually ( this button then makes a new request to update the data)
3. Use Websockets to send data immediatly after creation of a new Product to the client.

Last one requires some more work.

The easiest way would be to use `setInterval` or to create a refresh button. I show you an example for setInterval:

```
myInterval; //You need this to clear it later
...
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(data=> {
        this.listOfData = data;
        console.log('data', data);
      });
    }, 60000)
  } 

ngOnDestroy() {
   clearInterval(myInterval)
}
```

As long as the component is active, it will request new data every 60 seconds. You need to implement OnDestroy to clear the interval when the component gets destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to repeat your request. Another possible solution would be a [`websocket`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws) connection for getting information in real time.

For example:

Client A creates a product. Your backend writes it to the database and tells all listening clients via websocket connection that there is a new product.

Client B receives this information and triggers a new "getProducts" request.

Comment: yes, that is a possible solution but i wanna know why doesn't work with observable why the subscription not work, I would like use the full potential of angular rxjs.